# Error while sending email from Console application

Tags: c#, smtp, console-application

I am trying to send mail from a console application but it's throwing an error:

> Failure Sending Mail

I can not understand what's causing the error. I tried the same code on another machine and it's working fine. Here is the stacktrace:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebExceptio
n: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketExceptio
n: The requested address is not valid in its context 66.96.147.108:25
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddre
ss socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Sock
et s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state,
IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object ow
ner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket
6, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32
 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate
 asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncD
elegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at PaymentReminder.Program.SendMail(List`1 SourceList) in C:\Documents and Se
ttings\amols\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PaymentReminder\PaymentRem
inder\Program.cs:line 110
InnerException is: System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote serv
er ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested address is not valid i
n its context 66.96.147.108:25
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddre
ss socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Sock
et s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state,
IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object ow
ner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket
6, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32
 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate
 asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncD
elegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

Here is my code:

```
List<PaymentReminderList> prList = SourceList;            
MailAddress fromMail = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FromEmail"));
string NetworkUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Network_UserName");
string Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Password");
string Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Host");
int Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Port"));
string FromMail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FromEmail");
string ToMail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ToMail");
string mailBody = "Respected xxx, <br>This is Test Mail.<br> [[List]]  <br><br> Sincerely, <br> ABC<br>";

string mailContent = "";

foreach (var item in prList)
{
    mailContent += "" + item.abc + " | " + item.pqr + " | " + item.xyz+"<br>";
}

mailBody.Replace("[[List]]", mailContent);

//Console.WriteLine("Mail To");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress(ToMail);

//Console.WriteLine("Mail From");
MailAddress from = new MailAddress(FromMail);

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);

Console.WriteLine("Subject");
mail.Subject = "This is a Reminder Mail";

Console.WriteLine("Your Message");
//mail.Body = Console.ReadLine();
mail.Body = mailBody;

mail.From = from;
mail.To.Add(to);

mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;

System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
NetworkCred.UserName = NetworkUser;
NetworkCred.Password = Password;

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(Host, Port);
smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;

Console.WriteLine("Sending email...");

try
{
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);   //Should print stacktrace + details of inner exception

    if (ex.InnerException != null)
        Console.WriteLine("InnerException is: {0}", ex.InnerException);
}
```

Comment: What is your code looks like?

Comment: @SonerGönül I have added my code

Comment: The error is clear a connection to the address could not be establish.  You sure that information is correct?

Comment: @Ramhound as I posted in question I have tried this code on another machine where it is working without any error or exception

Comment: @Ashutosh - There is nothing wrong with your code.  So unless this computer was on the same network, it working on another computer, doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

Does the remote machine implement Secure SMTP? If so, you'll need to set the port property to 465.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.port.aspx

Comment: Hmm... I'll pick my brain some more. Other than that, it could be a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with my own mail server and it worked fine there.

The problem might be in your configuration. You use authentication in your code, and that usually requires enabled SSL for the connection (see [SmtpClient.EnableSsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx)), and setting the port to 465. Port 25 usually doesn't require authentication.

Comment: I am using port 25 and it is working fine on other machine and web app

Comment: Perhaps you can try connecting manually with telnet to the SMTP server from the machine you have problems on, just to see what happens during the connection phase better. Based on the exception message, it looks like a network issue.